# Can Android emulator capture key-press event of PC keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard

Can the Android emulator capture a key-press event of the computer (running the emulator) keyboard, such as: direction key, backspace key and enter key? If it could do that, can you tell me the key code of the implentation? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping between PC keyboard keys and devices keys is detailed here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping

And you can respond to them using the keycodes that are listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

For instance:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("test", "onKeyDown(" + keyCode + ", " + event +")");
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: what about the hard keyboard in some devices? will they work for them too?

Comment: @fiddler, thanks for your reply. From the website your gave, i know that emulator can not capture the key events of direction keys(left/up/right/down),am i right?

Comment: I think it can. I just tested it and noticed that direction keys and escape key seem to work (e.g I can navigate in the menus with the arrow keys of the PC keyboard)

Comment: @fiddler, i just want to ask u something more. why can not emulator capture the key events of 'Backspace' and 'Enter' of HID keyboard